# Binding of format type

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to dynamically assign formatting to fields based on formatted in my data structures; my templates are far too generic to define with formatting types already specified, even to the type. I.e. I have an attribute defined in scope for the actual data, and an attribute defined in scope for the formatting.

E.g.
$scope.data = '123.456' and $scope.format = 'number:2' should display '123.45'
OR
$scope.data = '2013-12-10 23:59:00' and $scope.format = 'date:yyyy-MM-hh' should display '2013-12-10'.

I can do binding like *{{data | number:}}*, but I can't do *{{data | }}.

I've created a very basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u0pf891/)

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = '1234567';
  $scope.format = 'number:2';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  
  <p>
    Data = <input type="text" ng-model="data" />
  </p>
  
  <p>
    Format = <input type="text" ng-model="format" />
  </p>
  
  <br />
  
  <p>
    Unformatted data = {{data}}
  </p>
  
  <p>
    Formatted data = <!--{{data | format}}-->
  </p>
</div>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: `{{data}}` is equivalent to `<ANY ng-model="data"></ANY>`, so I suggest formatting it within a directive with `<ANY ng-model="data" format-number></ANY>` syntax or something similar. It could be that you need [ngModelController $formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters)

Answer (score 1):

in such a case i'm not sure its possible in the HTML, i think you need to create your own filter/func that accepts the 2 and evals the results, probably with [$compile](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx) or [$parse and $interpolate](https://www.webcodegeeks.com/javascript/angular-js/magic-parse-service-angularjs/) [not $eval btw] (provided simple examples via links)

Comment: Agreed, that's my current thinking too; I'm looking at that option right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = '1234567';
  $scope.format = 'number';
  $scope.formatExp = '2';
  $scope.getFormattedContent = function() {
      return $filter($scope.format)($scope.data, $scope.formatExp);
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <p>
    Data = <input type="text" ng-model="data" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Format = <input type="text" ng-model="format" />
  </p>
  <p>
    FormatExp = <input type="text" ng-model="formatExp" />
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>
    Unformatted data = {{data}}
  </p>
  <p>
    Formatted data = {{getFormattedContent()}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom filter that accepts a config object and based on parsing the config object returns whatever format you need.

This could easily be extended to store various configurations in a service so controller would only need to inject service and pass service config objects to view or inject the service into the filter to access config objects etc

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.filter('dynamicFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(input, config) {

    if (!config) return input;

    switch (config.type) {
      // date and number use same setup - $filter with one argument
      case 'date':
      case 'number':
        return $filter(config.type)(input, config.arg);
        break;

      case 'pseudo-filter':
        // do something else to input
        return input

      default: // no match for config.type
        return input
    }
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.myNumber = 22.555567;
  $scope.filters = {
    number: {
      type: 'number',
      arg: 2
    },
    date: {
      type: 'date',
      arg: "MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <p>myDate: {{myDate | dynamicFilter:filters.date}}</p>

  <p>myNumber: {{myNumber | dynamicFilter:filters.number}}</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inspiration from a number of answers (specifically bresleveloper, charlietfl, and NiK648), I've come up with the final solution...

This uses basically the approaches suggested, but made a little more generic to work with more filter types...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uaevy720/) example

```js
var siteApp = angular.module('SiteApp', []);

siteApp.controller('TodoCtrl', function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = '1234.567';
  $scope.format = 'number:2';
});


siteApp.filter('DynamicFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, fmt) {
        if (fmt === undefined || fmt === null) {
            return input;
        }
        else {
            var tokens = fmt.split(':');

            if (tokens.length === 1) {
                return $filter(tokens[0])(input);
            }
            else if (tokens.length === 2) {
                return $filter(tokens[0])(input, tokens[1]);
            }
            else {
                console.error('Unsupported number of arguments in DynamicFilter [' + tokens.length + '].');
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="SiteApp" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  
  <p>
    Data = <input type="text" ng-model="data" />
  </p>
  
  <p>
    Format = <input type="text" ng-model="format" />
  </p>
  
  <br />
  
  <p>
    Unformatted data = {{data}}
  </p>
  
  <p>
    Formatted data = {{data | DynamicFilter:format}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Thank you all for your help, much appreciated.